# Android Studio - why does my mouse over tooltip keep disappearing

Tags: android-studio

Whilst using Android Studio I am getting this error when I mouse over the text associated with `android:name`. However, when I move the mouse down to click on `more` the tooltip disappears. Also the shortcut `Cmd F1` does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is your Android Studio version btw ?

Comment: 1.2.1.1 (some pointless text so that I can post this comment)

Comment: I am on 1.2.1.1 too but it doesn't happen to me. Seems like a small bug in AS. You would want to report it in their issue lists.

Comment: Have you tried using `Fn Cmd F1`? Some systems require you to do this when you use a function key with an actual system control.